# Views relationship using taxonomy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have two content types (document and employee) and both have a reference to a taxonomy (language). I would like to build a view showing all documents that a employee could read. In other words, both of them have the same language.

I've try to relate the employee and the taxonomy; however, I can't see a way to relate the taxonomy to the document. I've also tried to relate directly the employee language ID to the document language ID, with no success.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing you need to sort the node using the taxonomy fields. Is it so then use the steps:

1. Add realtionship in views
   [image: Relationship]
2. Then add 'taxonomy terms on node'
   [image: term related to node]
3. Then go to filter then you can find all the terms there
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

[EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) module can help you with that. It enables you to attach a views display to an entity, and pass arguments from the entity to views to filter the views results.

With it you can create a list of documents, set the views display to show on employee content type, and set the taxonomy term as the filtering argument.

You can find more details about how to set it up here: [EVA field: file entities filtered by taxonomy term of attaching node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/160476/eva-field-file-entities-filtered-by-taxonomy-term-of-attaching-node/180904#180904)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an Argument for *Taxonomy: Term ID* and provide Default Arg - PHP

Then paste this code:

```
if (arg(0) != 'node') {
  return;
}
$node = node_load(arg(1));
if ($node && $node->taxonomy) {
    foreach($node->taxonomy as $term) { $terms[] = $term->tid; }
    return implode('+', $terms);
}
return;
```

[Source](http://drupal.org/node/65375#comment-3386654)