# How to filter on taxonomy term in a view?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I've got a view where I would like to filter content based on a taxonomy term. I've created the taxonomy, added some terms, created a field reference on the specific content type I'd like to show, then added some terms to content.

The issue I have is this: In the view, under add new filter, the taxonomy I created doesn't show up as an option to filter by. There's a bunch of "indexed node: xxx" available, but none of them refers to the taxonomy I created. I suppose there is an option somewhere to have the taxonomy terms indexed? How do I do this?

This might seem like a very straightforward question, but for some reason on this particular website, I can't find the culprit.

Comment: Are you using SearchAPI or Solr?

Comment: I don't even know to be honest! How can I check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a relationship to your taxonomy vocabulary. Think of this like adding a join to a mySQL query.

For more info, take a look at [Views relationship using taxonomy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14804/views-relationship-using-taxonomy)

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck! I'm quite puzzled, I've done this before on other websites and I usually don't even have to add the relationship. Here even adding the relationship doesn't work.

Comment: @pim `I usually don't even have to add the relationship.` That only happens when you create a **taxonomy view, [see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZPiw.jpg)**. If you create a **content view**, then you will need the relationship.